# QLineEdit can only be used once

Tags: pyqt

I'm facing the issue that my code works for the first line edit only:

[image: img]

For this I'm using this code:

```
    lineedit = QLineEdit(self)
    validator = QIntValidator()
    lineedit.setValidator(validator)
    

    layout = QGridLayout()
    j = 0
    layout.addWidget(QLabel('Tube: '), j+1, 0)
    layout.addWidget(lineedit, j+1, 1)
```

so I thought I could simply use this element / code line for every element of the grid:

```
    lineedit = QLineEdit(self)
    validator = QIntValidator()
    lineedit.setValidator(validator)
    

    layout = QGridLayout()
    j = 0
    layout.addWidget(QLabel('Tube: '), j+1, 0)
    layout.addWidget(lineedit, j+1, 1)
    layout.addWidget(QLabel('Date: '), j+2, 0)
    layout.addWidget(QLineEdit(), j+2, 1)
    ...
```

but this turns out into:

[image: img2]

I could probably rename this button `lineedit` into `lineedit_j` and count `j` up. But is there a smarter way?

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre].

Comment: The last code doesn't match what you're showing in the image. You're probably trying to add the same `lineedit` object for each layout cell, which doesn't make any sense: widgets are just like physical objects, you cannot put the same object in more places, if you put a shirt in a closet and then want to put it in another closet, you don't end up with two shirts in two closets.

Comment: that makes totally sense
but couldn't I copy a shirt over and over and give them different names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep separate instances of each of the widgets.
I recommend subclassing the QLineEdit to encapsulate the validator.

```
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QLineEdit, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIntValidator
import sys


#Subclass QLineEdit to include the Integer Validator
class IntEdit(QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        validator = QIntValidator()
        self.setValidator(validator)


class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

        def __init__(self):
            super(Ui, self).__init__()

            layout = QGridLayout()

            # List to hold widgets
            self.widgets = [] 

            for w in range(15):
                widget = IntEdit(self)
                layout.addWidget(widget, w % 5, w % 3)
                self.widgets.append(widget)

            self.setCentralWidget(QWidget(self))
            self.centralWidget().setLayout(layout)
            self.show()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec()
```

[Example GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwJ74.png)

You could also consider using a QTableWidget or QTreeView instead of the grid layout.  You could add the custom IntEdit widget to the cell items of those parent controls.